# iPhone CoreLocation accuracy

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-location

I am trying to find the latitude and longitude position of rooms within my house.

Assuming that there is a clear signal, is this possible?. If I use the center of the room as a point, there is about 8-10 meters distance between each of the rooms.

What kind of accuracy can I obtain? Are there any other methods? (I'm assuming that this is impractical?)

Also, I started looking at CoreLocation and outing the lat and long as labels but i dont quite understand why the coordinates keep changing? (the iPhone is stationary)

Comment: Are you trying to determine where the phone is as it moves around within the house?  Or trying to measure the lat/lon for a room?  If the latter, you can take a long term average of the lat/lon readings to average out the noise.  It may take minutes or hours depending on how accurate you want to get.

Comment: Not quite, the phone is stationary in the center of the room. I'm playing around with an AR application and wish to know the exact coordinates of the center room. The coordinates i receive are usually erroneous

Comment: How erroneous?  by how much?  What accuracy did you request from CL?  What accuracy does it say you have in the CL given?  I get good (+/-10m) locations from CL indoors but it may be based on WiFi hotspots (I have several) more than GPS data.

Comment: Well in all honesty it seems its around the margin you stated +/- 10m. I managed to get good reading of the center of the room but i realized that the users position also needs to settle (which itself is +/-10m) which overall on a 'bad' day i imagine the readings could be extremely off with the slightest disruption. =/

Answer (score 3):

You won't get accuracy that good.  The best you can expect is to within about 10m (30') of the correct location when you have a good GPS signal (clear view of the sky) and the signal is poor when indoors.  The GPS accuracy spec is actually 100m but you usually can get 10m in practice if you can see many satellites (4-12).  There is an [accuracy table for GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System#Comparison_of_Accuracy) in Wikipedia.  The iPhone does not have WAAS correction (which is very hard to get indoors anyway).

The coordinates keep changing because there are errors and noise on the GPS signals.  The atmospheric delay changes with air density which varies with high altitude winds, clouds, moisture content, etc.  The satellites are moving so you also get variable geometry which changes the calculated location.  Satellites drop below the horizon and others popup which changes the set of satellites that you are calculating position from.

With a *lot* of work (software development) you could integrate data from the compass, accelerometers and gyros into an [Inertial Navigation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) that could measure movement like this.  iPhone4 and iPad2 have all of those sensors built in.

Comment: Is there a more accurate way to approach this indoors? what other technology is available?

Comment: On the iPhone?  It's GPS or INS.  It doesn't have any other suitable sensors built in.  Or you could put bluetooth emitters in each room and scan to see which ones are visible and deduce your location that way perhaps.  Not very practical.

Comment: So hypothetically speaking if you wanted to deduce the exact position of a stationary object within a room its near impossible?. Also assuming that there is no signal within the building but the iphone is connected via wifi, would it still be able to locate the users position?

Comment: There is no such thing as exact in this context.  How much accuracy do you want?  For $10k you can buy a surveyor's GPS with will give you 10cm accuracy.

Comment: WiFi does not provide location information unless it can be looked up in a database created by a car that drove by and recorded that there was XYZ wifi signal visible when it was at xxx/yyy GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Core location uses three different methods to determine the location. These are cell tower triangulation, Wi-Fi location data and GPS.

Depending on the value of CLLocationManager's desiredAccuracy parameter, it will use one or more of these three methods to determine the device's location.

The reason the location keeps changing is that the longer you wait, the more accurate (usually) your results get. So for example:

1. It first determines a very rough location using cell tower triangulation
2. Then it finds one or two wi-fi hotspots and gets a better fix on the location
3. It then finds some more hotspots and therefore gets an even better fix
4. Finally, if GPS is available, you get the best fix possible

Of course it takes a long time (and a lot of power) for GPS to become available. This is both due to the way GPS works, and because iOS turns GPS off to conserve power.

To answer your main question, if you have a GPS signal (i.e. you're outdoors), and there are at least a few wi-fi hotspots around you that are in Apple's database, you can potentially get a location fix to within 10 meters. Indoors, however, the best you can expect is around 100m.

Comment: Most devices are capable of getting better than 100M indoors. Between cell-triangulation, wifi, and limited GPS... it can probably get better than 10M. Granted a lot goes into accuracy, but 100M is a little extreme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use core motion / sensor aiding, but that could help you only with relative location rather than absolute. Those devices have a much better accuracy that cell/wifi/gps, especially for indoor navigation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? The accelerometer and gyroscope within the iphone detect the users movement but how could this improve user tracking? (assuming that the user itself is +/- 10m out of bounds)

Answer (score 1):

I have used my GPS indoors with some success, but most of the prior answers are right, the level of accuracy needed to map individual rooms is going to take quite a bit of work. And all of that is assuming your device can even get a GPS fix inside the house.

As far as your coordinates changing while not moving... that is all related to how good a fix you are getting from your device. While your device is checking for location updates, -startUpdatingLocation, you will get a lot of little corrections to location as it is constantly being updated. Hope that answers some of your questions.